# Taking Over Ownership

Tags: security, permissions, ownership

So I took ownership over a folder and then I deleted the folder. Does that effect ownership security of the rest of folder in mast folder?

Folder I deleted was a duplicate I made, it was nothing important.

For example this is the folder hierarchy

```
 Directory of E:\Users\**\Desktop\PC

    08/23/2015  11:06 PM    <DIR>          .
    08/23/2015  11:06 PM    <DIR>          ..
    08/23/2015  11:06 PM    <DIR>          Important Folder 1
    08/23/2015  11:05 PM    <DIR>          Important Folder 2
```

so if I took owner ship of "ImportantFolder 1" and deleted it. Would that effect the security of folder "PC" and the "Important folder 2"?

Comment: No it wouldn't. deleting "Important Folder 1" won't affect "Important Folder 2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Taking ownership of a folder does not affect the permissions of files or folders outside that folder.

- Taking ownership of a folder typically would, however, affect the permissions of its contents, including any subfolders. This is because folder contents are set by default to inherit the permissions of the parent folder. Any files or folders not inside the folder you're taking ownership of are not affected.